# Why is Python sort faster than that of C++

Tags: python, c++, performance, sorting

Sorting a list of ints in python 3 seems to be faster than sorting an array of ints in C++. Below is the code for 1 python program and 2 C++ programs that I used for the test. Any reason why the C++ programs are slower? It doesn't make sense to me.

----- Program 1 - python 3.4 -----

```
from time import time

x = 10000
y = 1000

start = time()

for _ in range(y):
    a = list(range(x))
    a.reverse()
    a.sort()

print(round(time() - start, 2), 'seconds')
```

----- Program 2 - c++ using sort from algorithm  ------

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main(){

    int x = 10000; 
    int y = 1000;
    int b[10000];

    cout << "start" << endl;

    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++){
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
            b[i] = x - i;
        } // still slower than python with this clause taken out

        sort(b, b + x); // regular sort

    }

    cout << "done";
    system("pause");
}
```

----- Program 3 - c++ using hand written merge sort ------

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

void merge(int * arr, int *temp, int first_start, int second_start, int      second_finish){

    int a1 = first_start, b1 = second_start, r = 0;

    while (a1 < second_start && b1 < second_finish){

        if (arr[a1] < arr[b1]){
            temp[r] = arr[a1];
            a1++; r++;
        }
        else {
            temp[r] = arr[b1];
            b1++; r++;
        }
    }
    if (a1 < second_start){

        while (a1 < second_start){
            temp[r] = arr[a1];
            a1++; r++;
        }
    }

    else {
        while (b1 < second_finish){
            temp[r] = arr[b1];
            b1++; r++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = first_start; i < second_finish; i++){
        arr[i] = temp[i - first_start];
    }
}

void merge_sort(int *a, int a_len, int *temp){
    int c = 1, start = 0;
    while (c < a_len){
        while (start + c * 2 < a_len){
            merge(a, temp, start, start + c, start + c * 2);
            start += c * 2;
        }
        if (start + c <= a_len){
            merge(a, temp, start, start + c, a_len);
        }
        c *= 2; start = 0;
    } 
}

int main(){

    int x = 10000; // size of array to be sorted
    int y = 1000; // number of times to sort it
    int b[10000], temp[10000]; 

    cout << "start" << endl;

    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++){

        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){

            b[i] = x - i; // reverse sorted array (even with this assignment taken out still runs slower than python)

        }

        merge_sort(b, x, temp);

    }

    cout << "done";
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Did you compile the C++ code with optimizations enabled? EDIT: When compiling the `std::sort` example with gcc 4.9 and `-O2`, it's faster than the python code in python3 by a factor of somewhere between 3 and 4 for me. Without optimizations, it's slower by a factor of somewhere between 2 and 3. Optimization matters.

Comment: What are your times?

Comment: 0.19 seconds for the python code, 0.45 seconds for unoptimized C++, 0.05 seconds for optimized C++. Variance is fairly high because the test time is so short.

Comment: Which standard library are you using?

Comment: libstdc++. With libc++, it's even faster, and even the unoptimized C++ is faster than python with it. (0.12 seconds unoptimized with gcc 4.9, 0.045 optimized). And optimized with clang gives 0.025 seconds, which is the best result yet.

Comment: I wish people would stop timing unoptimized code.  It is meaningless.

Comment: My run of C++ was 4 times faster than python. Unoptimized C++ is purely for debugging purposes.

Comment: On my machine even the unoptimized C++ version is five times as fast as the python version, with I/O counted.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The core reason is no doubt **timsort** -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort -- first conceived by Tim Peters for Python though now also in some Java VMs (for non-primitives only).

It's a truly amazing algorithm and you can find a C++ implementation at https://github.com/swenson/sort for example.

Lesson to retain: the proper *architecture* and *algorithms* can let you run circles around supposedly-faster *languages* if the latter are using less-perfect A & As!-)  So, if you have really big problems to solve, deal with determining perfect architecture and algorithms first -- the language and optimizations within it are inevitably lower-priority issues.

Comment: I rather doubt that. The generated data is the worst case for Timsort.

Comment: I think the take-away is rather this: compile C++ code with optimization enabled! Unoptimized C++ isn't great at all.

Comment: I made one change to the merge sort version that got c++ running faster than python (moved the declaration of the temp array to the main body).

Comment: Benchmark the C++ code again with a release build. Chances are they'll all be faster than the python code. The search algorithm has little to do with it, except that maybe it puts Python at an even worse disadvantage because the test data is structured in a bad way for Timsort. Benchmarking debug builds is about the only way Python could win this shootout. And yes, I am saying that this answer is horribly wrong.

Comment: @Wintermute Perhaps Tim Peters predicted for that and the "minrun" step simultaneously goes backwards and forwards at the same time and picks up not only segments that are already sorted in the desired order but also sorted in the *reverse* of the desired order. Just a guess, however, but I really have a strong feeling that the reverse-order issue is solved before it even gets to the insertion sorting step.

Comment: @Wintermute: I entirely agree that this answer is wrong. I guess, it got upvoted and accepted because python people like to think their fancy timsort has an edge.

Comment: @DietmarKühl It's not a bad algorithm, but it's not the answer to this question.

Comment: I believe TimSort is a perfectly valid choice for `std::sort` if an implementation wishes.

Comment: @chris That is true. Regardless, the deciding factors in all this are likely to be  that the C++ implementation can 1. use machine words where python has to use complex data types, 2. pack the data tightly in memory (good for cache locality), and 3. use SSE instructions (both gcc and clang do this; gcc only with `-O3`). The choice of sorting algorithm, if restricted to sane ones, plays a secondary role.

Comment: @Wintermute, Rather reminds me of the linked list vs. dynamic array thing, where the prefetching for the latter can do a surprising amount of good in situations the former is meant for.

Comment: @chris Using timsort for `std::sort` is very improbable. Although it would be standard-compliant (as the standard doesn't require a specific memory complexity for sort), the use of O(N) auxiliary memory during the sort is not something that people would easily accept as the default/standard sorting algorithm. The STL `<algorithm>` implementers usually make it a big point to avoid any kind of auxiliary memory (O(N) on heap or stack, either way, it's not good). Pretty much, only O(logN) memory on stack is acceptable.

Comment: With an array of just 10k items, it **is** possible that an inferior algorithm with a faster implementation can beat a superior one with a less-fast implementation (@Wintermute's mention of machine words vs boxed data types, resulting locality, &c, is quite cogent).  But -- try with ten **million** items (rather than a mere ten **thousands**) and, let me know how it goes for you!-)  "The choice of sorting algorithm ... plays a secondary role" only for **relatively small** problems -- make them big enough, and big-O will mean a **lot** more!-)

Comment: Big-O is the same for all sane sorting algorithms.

Comment: I just ran the python and `std::sort` C++ codes with 10 million items. clang++ with libc++ and -O2 takes 23.1 seconds. Python3 takes 281.3 seconds.

Comment: @Wintermute, no it's not -- not for sequences with some initial aspects of sortedness or anti-sortedness, as in this code and often in real life.  timsort is O(N) for many of these, vs O(N logN) for typical sort algorithms.  (When applicable, radix sort can also get O(N) -- but it's only applicable occasionally, while timsort's always applicable, preternaturally fast sometimes but O(N logN) worst-case).  Re-read "Programming Pearls", specifically the very first entry http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/cto.html , ``How do I sort a disk file?'', to remind you of another example!-)

Comment: Have you actually run a benchmark before answering?

Comment: @Wintermute no I haven't, can you point me to any Stack Overflow instruction saying that I should?-)

Comment: It would have been prudent in this case, given that C++ code, compiled with optimizations by a common compiler, turns out to be faster by a factor of ~8 for small sets and faster by a factor of ~12 for large sets. Empirical data does not agree with your argument. You are, of course, free to finally test whether what you're saying is actually true.

Comment: Pypy is doing much better, by the way. It takes 54.1 seconds for 10 million elements (lagging by a factor of 2.34). For smaller sets, the gap is a little more narrow; factor 2 for 100000 elements, and below that it gets hard to measure reliably; the difference does not appear to be very large there.

Comment: Digging a bit deeper still, it turns out that of the 281.3 seconds that Python3 takes to run the code, roughly 200 are spent in `a = list(range(x))`  (~185 seconds) and `a.reverse()` (~15 seconds). Of the 23.1 seconds that the C++ code takes, 4.2 are spent reversing the input data, so for the actual sorting step Python3 is just slower by a factor of ~4. With Pypy, the sorting step alone is roughly as fast as the C++ sorting step. This is only mildly surprising given the way Pypy works.

Comment: @Wintermute That generated data isn't the worst case but the **second-best** case (after the case of input sorted ascendingly) for Timsort. It's O(n) on this, taking only n-1 comparisons and O(1) extra space to detect the descending run and reverse it in place.